# Generic Subject class Observor Pattern

Tags: c++, subject-observer

I have been giving the following problem to solve. Make a generic Subject class (referring to Observor Pattern) such that it can accept any data type( primitive or user type). The register, remove and notify functions are also required to be customizable.
As an example, we have a WeatherStation class which notifies observors on data type 'int'. It makes a DB entry on registering and removing observors.

Another example(not shown) is BroadcastHandler which notifies observors on stock exchange quotes. It makes entry in files on registering and removing observors.

I wrote the following code to implement it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <class T>
class Observor
{
  public :
  virtual void update(const T& t) = 0;
  virtual ~Observor(){}
};

template<class T>
class Subject
{
  public :
  virtual void registerObservor(Observor<T>* obv) = 0;
  virtual void removeObservor(Observor<T>* obv) = 0;
  virtual void notifyObservors(T t);
  virtual ~Subject(){}
};

template<class T>
class WeatherStation : public Subject<T>
{
  public :
  void registerObservor(Observor<T>* obv)
  {
    _observors.insert(obv);
    //Make DB Entry
  }

  void removeObservor(Observor<T>* obv)
  {
    if(_observors.find(obv) != _observors.end())
    {
        _observors.erase(obv);
        //Make DB Entry
    }
  }

  void notifyObservors(T t)
  {
    for(auto itr = _observors.begin(),
    itrEnd = _observors.end(); itr != itrEnd; ++itr)
    {
        (*itr)->update(t);
    }
  }

private :
std::set< Observor<T>* > _observors;
};

int main()
{
  WeatherStation<int> wStation;
}
```

I get the following error from the linker

```
observor_pattern.o:observor_pattern.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV7SubjectIiE[__ZTV7SubjectIiE]+0x10)||undefined reference to `Subject<int>::notifyObservors(int)'
```

Comment: Is all this code in one file?

Comment: On purpose for now, I will shift the subject and observor base classes to another file once I have working code

Comment: I've just thought initialy that you might have forgotten that template implementation must be included into header, but now I see another reason for the linker error, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed (as the linker tells you) you do not have definition of `Subject<T>::notifyObservors(T)`, and you did not declare it as `=0`. Was this intentional? I think a proper code might be

```
template<class T>
class Subject
{
  public :
  virtual void registerObservor(Observor<T>* obv) = 0;
  virtual void removeObservor(Observor<T>* obv) = 0;
  virtual void notifyObservors(T t) = 0;
                               //   ^^^
  virtual ~Subject(){}
};
```

Though even a better approach would be to have all observor-handling code in `Subject`, not in `WeatherStation`, because that seems to be what `Subject` class is all about. It's `Subject`'s responsibility to handle `Observor`s, and `WeatherStation`'s responsibility should be to get data from sensors, etc.

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks. It wasnt intentional @Petr, it was a silly mistake. As to putting the handling code in Subject, it dosent fulfill my purpose. Different circumstances require different handling by Subject(eg: make entry in DB/ make entry in File). I can satisfy that by using inheritance+polymorphism. I can however put a default implementation in Subject(which I currently dont wish to)

Comment: @PranavKapoor, then you might consider having one `Subject` and several its subclasses for just different treatment. But what you say seems even more appropriate for `Observor` itself: a `DBWriterObservor`, a `FileWriterObservor`, etc — that definitely sounds as an `Observor` responsibility.

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong @Petr. Arent observors supposed to care only about the data(in this case ints) they receive? Shouldnt the responsibiity of logging the registering and removing of observors lie with subject itself.

Comment: @PranavKapoor, oh, you talk about logging observer change, not logging the data? Then yes, that's not for `Observer`.